The water in my toilet tank won’t fill up after a flush if the tank lid is on. But it will fill after a flush if the lid is off
I can’t find anything on the web that addresses this.

the lid is interfering with something ... figure out what that something is

Sounds obvious but I have examined everything physical with the lid.  It’s literally just sitting on top of the porcelain.  Not to mention this randomly started happening.

What exactly is or is not happening?  Please add details to the question.  Is the water running, entering the tank and flowing into the bowl?   Is it not flowing?  What sounds do you hear (or not hear) with the lid on?    If you flush with the lid off and it starts filling, and you replace the lid after five seconds, does it stop filling?  What exactly do you see or hear then?  What about the opposite experiment?

place a large cutting board on top of the tank ... see if it is interfering with anything

@Jsotola Or just cover the top with plastic wrap and watch what happens.

Is the float on the end of a long rod?  Maybe it's bumping into the top as the water rises.

@Duston then the water would not stop

If you take a picture of the innards of the toilet tank and post it in the question, someone may notice something to investigate.  Along with the results of the jay613 suggestions.  The lid interfering mechanically is the obvious possibility.  Another alternative is that the lid is changing the pressure in the tank.  Not sure what might be vulnerable to that.  The flapper?  The inlet?  This tickles my memory with regards to the flapper, but not so much as to provide a solution.
